# SuperSocket can't set up a server

Tags: c#, supersocket.net

I am writing this to find out why the code below is resulting in failed setup for supersocket server.

```
    var appServer = new AppServer();
    if (!appServer.Setup(8080)){
        MessageBox.Show("Failed!");
    }
```

I have added rule in firewall that allows port 8080 since my firewall is enabled by company IT. Don't know why the setup fails. Is there an explanation?

Comment: if you enable the logging for debug and error it might show the error in the log files - but from the Port Number 8080 it seems like this port is being used by some program - try another port number e.g. 9199

Comment: Not as much Ez pz with little info provided, post the debug log.

Comment: @Luicy, you should provide the exception details/stack trace or additional info else the bounty is wasted

Answer (score 3):

In testing this locally in a console application using the following (requires NuGet packages `SuperSocket` and `SuperSocket.Engine`;

```
namespace SupersocketTest
{
    using System;
    using SuperSocket.SocketBase;

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var server = new AppServer();
            bool success = server.Setup(8080);
            Console.WriteLine($"Server setup: {success}");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

The operation completes successfully.

Looking at the [code](https://github.com/kerryjiang/SuperSocket) online, the underlying connection is still `Socket` based (as the name of the package implies). As such, it's subject to all the rules around how sockets work normally in .NET.

Things that can cause a [Socket](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.sockets.socket.listen?view=netframework-4.7.1#System_Net_Sockets_Socket_Listen_System_Int32_) fail to be set up are (but not limited to)

- The socket is in use
- The socket has been closed
- The OS has run out of available sockets (not likely but technically possible)

Without more detail on the exception you're getting I can only guess but I suspect that the socket is in use as `8080` is a common alternative to `80` that another application could be using.